# People Picker not getting populated in the Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

Here i am facing some weird issue. I have a People Picker, which is being populated from a SharePoint list based on the selection in the dropdown. The data connections are made properly and the functionality is working as expected when i do a Preview in the Infopath 2010. But when i publish the Infopath in the Sharepoint site, the functionality is not working. When i perform the necessary action the rule to set the People picker is not working. Following are the values of the People Picker that i am setting in the Rule- AccountID Display Name & Account Type. Can someone please help me in this issue.

To be more precise,

I have a sharepoint list--> tower(Id, TowerName [Text datatype], Tower Lead A[people Picket datatype], Tower Bead B [Text datatype]).

I have a dropdown which is getting populated from the tower name from the sharepoint list.

When i select the Tower in the dropdown, the Tower Lead A and Tower Lead B is to be populated in the Infopath form.

This thing is working fine for Tower Lead A and Tower Lead B (i can see this because in the Preview it works fine) but when i do a publish, the same does not work for the population of the People Picker datafield. where in Tower Lead B is working.

I hope i am clear now with the problem. I have checked the data connections as well, but not able to find the issue. Please provide inputs.

Appreciate your quick help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I finally found why i was facing this issue.

In the dropDown list in Infopath we are having Postback settings- where you get 3 options,

Always, Never and Only when necessary for correct rendering of the form.

Earlier the dropdown was set with the 3rd option. But i changed it to Always, so the functionality started working.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful for me.